# Node.js MongoDB error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The error is: the update operation document must contain atomic operators.

```
db.get().collection('users').updateOne(query, newvalues, function (err, result) {
    cb(err,result)
  })
```

I already use the $set operator. I just printed on the console both query and newvalues and i cant find any mistake.

```
query: { username: 'macarra' }
newvalues: { $set: {name: "Mojo Picon",email: "mako@gmail.es"} }
```

Comment: I think i found the mistake, a really stupid one. I tryed to append to newvalues using the string operands "+=" so propably newvalues was not a JSON object anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the object with the new values:

```
var obj = {
   name: "Mojo Picon",
   email: "mako@gmail.es"
}
```

to build the newvalues object required by the updateOne method you need to:

```
var newvalues = {
   $set: obj
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify this worked for me: await collection.updateOne(filter, {$set: updateObject })

Answer (score 0):

sample code for update.

```
db.collection(collectionName).findOneAndUpdate
(
    {  
        documentStatus:req.body.documentStatus, 
        auditTrail:auditArray
    },
    { $addToSet: {"clientArray": clientArrayElem}},
    { upsert:true}
);
```

Please check official driver documentation or use noSQl booster IDE it will show you the query when you try editing document.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/

Comment: findOneAndUpdate() returns the document you updated, but im using the method updateOne